# Is there easy way to setup VGA passthrough on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: virtualization, vga

Does anyone success to setup VGA passthrough on Ubuntu 16.04?
What is the easiest way to do that?

I have installed virtual-manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  I have this working properly with libvirt now.  For me, the only complication was learning how to [fake out the Windows NVidia driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#.22Error_43_:_Driver_failed_to_load.22_on_Nvidia_GPUs_passed_to_Windows_VMs) to believe it is *not* running in a VM.  I did that by adding `<kvm><hidden state='on'/></kvm>` to the `<features>` block.  <s>, and `<timer name='hypervclock' present='no'/>` to the `<clock>` block</s>. *(Update 2: hypervclock now appears to be acceptable for modern NVidia drivers.)*

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

There is no "easy" way, and I have only had partial success directly adding the PCI device with libvirt / virtual-manager.  [I did have unqualified success following this guide.](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/)

However, I had to do a lot of reading in other tutorials and forums to understand what was going on.  [Here's the list of terminology I wish I'd had when I started](http://thundersuntech.blogspot.com/2017/02/virtualization-vga-passthrough-concepts.html).

The basic steps are:

- stub out your passthrough VGA device so Ubuntu doesn't claim it
- script a qemu commandline to...

  - add a ioh3420 virtual PCI root port
  - add your VGA device
  - add any other devices in the same IOMMU group as your VGA device
  - add a mouse/keyboard

Here's the script from the link above, all credit to the author, Matt Bach.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

configfile=/etc/virt/vfio-pci1.cfg

vfiobind() {
    dev="$1"
        vendor=$(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/vendor)
        device=$(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/device)
        if [ -e /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver ]; then
                echo $dev > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver/unbind
        fi
        echo $vendor $device > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

}

modprobe vfio-pci

cat $configfile | while read line;do
    echo $line | grep ^# >/dev/null 2>&1 && continue
        vfiobind $line
done

sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -M q35 -m 4096 -cpu host,kvm=off \
-name cmdline \
-smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 \
-bios /usr/share/qemu/bios.bin -vga none \
-usb \
-usbdevice host:046d:c52b,hostbus=3,hostaddr=7  \ // My logitech mouse/kb receiver
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=05:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=05:00.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1 \    
-drive file=/home/at/virt/windows1.img,id=disk,format=qcow2,cache=none,if=none -device ide-hd,drive=disk \
-drive file=/home/at/virt/win7.iso,id=isocd,cache=none,if=none,format=raw -device ide-cd,bus=ide.2,drive=isocd \
-boot menu=on
```

Comment: In particular, note the usbdevice argument.  I've specified both a vendor/device  AND a hostbus/hostaddr.  That's because I only want *one* of my two logitech receivers to be passed through.